# How to count the number of times a pair occurs across columns SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite

I want to write a SQL query to do the following.
I have the following table, lets call it test_table:

```
id1, id2, link_group
A, B, 1
A, B, 17
A, B, 12
A, C, 1
B, C, 1
D, E, 2
D, E, 5
```

I want to count the number of times pairs of columns id1, and id2 appear.  The result table would look like this.  Explicitly A, and B occurred together in three separate link_group categories, A,C and B,C in one link_group, and D, E in 2 link_groups.

```
id1, id2, coappearances
A, B, 3
A, C, 1
B, C, 1
D, E, 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT id1, id2, COUNT(1) AS coappearances
FROM test_table
GROUP BY id1, id2
```

Comment: Wow.  That easy.  I must be up too late!  Thankyou